# How to copy files into a newly created folder with the current date appended to the foldername

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io

I just copied a folder and appended the date to the name of the folder.  I would like to now copy files into a subfolder within the newly created folder.  Here is what I did originally to copy the folder and append the date:

```
Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now()
Dim strDate As String = regDate.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.copyFolder("C:\VB_Testing_Script\PB_Local\InterChange-",
"C:\VB_Testing_Script\PB_Local\InterChange-" & Format(regdate, "MMddyy"))
```

The output is then a folder called InterChange-022614
Within that folder are two other folders (appl and mar)

After the creation of the folder with the date in the filename, I need to copy files into the app folder.

Comment: Why not use System.IO namespace?
Create the folder in the specified location, and then copy your files using io.file.copy..
Also, when you mean "app folder" you mean the folder your .exe that started the application is? For that you could do file.copy(filetocopy, Application.startuppath & "\filename.exe")
For the date you could just use the "Now" property i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a folder then use IO.Directory.CreateDirectory.  If you want to copy a file then use IO.File.Copy.  When using date and/or times in file and folder names, you should always place units in decreasing order of magnitude.  That way, alphabetical order and chronological order will agree.  With that in mind, copying a file while appending the current date would look like this:

```vb
Dim fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFilePath)
Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(sourceFilePath)
Dim destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolderPath,
                                       String.Format("{0}_{1:yyyyMMdd}{2}",
                                                     fileName,
                                                     Date.Now,
                                                     extension))

File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath)
```

Comment: The newly created folder is InterChange-022614\appl.... But I don't know how to write the folder name to tell VB where to copy the files.....  EXAMPLE:  Copy files to c:\InterChange*\appl    (I don't know how to code the folder name with the current date, cause it will be different each time.  Please help.

Comment: The code I provided shows how to incorporate the current date.  it puts the date into the file name but it's just a String.  You can use the String.Format method in the same way to incorporate the date into any String.